# whats wrong on my msys2? can't get dirname at bash

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, mingw, msys2

my nodejs script can't work well at msys2 shell

something worng make $basedir always become empty

than case this bug `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\msys64\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js'`

how can i fix this?

---

msys2-bug-test

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

echo \$0 = $0

echo
echo \$\(dirname \"\$\(echo \"\$0\" \| sed -e \'s,\\,/,g\'\)\"\)
echo

echo \"$basedir\" should eq $(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
echo $(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')
```

will output

```
$ msys2-bug-test
$0 = /c/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/npm/msys2-bug-test

$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\,/,g')")

"" should eq .
/c/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/npm/msys2-bug-test
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
```

by:

```
basedir=$(dirname $(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g'))
```

And:

```
echo \"$basedir\" should eq $(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
echo $(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')
```

by:

```
echo \"$basedir\" should eq $(dirname $(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g'))
echo $(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')
```